# sieve data accordingly, when either of the inputs changed

Tags: java

Working Stackblitz:

I implemented 2 calendars in html, for filtering the data between 2 dates. When i filter data for the first time, i will select both calendar dates and the data is filtering. Now we have both the inputs for calendar given right. Now my issue lies here. When i change the first calendar date. the second calendar remains the same with previously assigned date as we filtered previously. and there is no change in the filtering of data until we give inputs to both calendars again. I want the second calendar value to be cleared on changing the first calendar. And also clear the first calendar input when the second calendar is changed. Please help me achieve this.

can we trigger the output based on either of the input values ? as of now it's not showing. example: i have 2 records in grid: with dates : 07/12/2020 and 15/12/2020 Initially if i filter from dec 1st 2020 to dec 31st 2020. It's showing both records. Now, again if i set 15/12/2020 in first calendar without changing second. There is no change in the table. i should enter second also. Can we fix it ??

```
<input type="date" (change)="changeFirstInput($event)"> - 
  <input type="date" (change)="changeSecondInput($event)">
  <table style="width:100%">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>date</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let o of display">  
          <td>{{o.name}}</td>
          <td>{{o.date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm a'}}</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
import { Component, VERSION, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  public obj = [{
    name: "abc",
    date: "2020-12-03 05:49:00"
  },{
    name: "def",
    date: "2020-12-07 05:49:00"
  },{
    name: "ghi",
    date: "2020-12-15 05:49:00"    
  },{
    name: "jkl",
    date: "2020-12-25 05:49:00"    
  }]

  ngOnInit() { this.display=this.obj; }


    pattern = /(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})/;
  public date1: Date = new Date("2000-01-01");
  public date2: Date = new Date();

  display = [];

  changeFirstInput(e) {
    this.date1 = new Date(e.target.value.replace(this.pattern, '$3-$2-$1'));
  }

  changeSecondInput(e) {
    this.display = Object.assign([], this.obj);
    this.date2 = new Date(e.target.value.replace(this.pattern, '$3-$2-$1'));

    this.display = this.obj.filter(o =>
    //   new Date(o.ts.replace(this.pattern, '$3-$2-$1')) >= this.date1 &&
     //  new Date(o.ts.replace(this.pattern, '$3-$2-$1')) <= this.date2);
      new Date(o.date.substring(0, 10)) >= this.date1 &&
      new Date(o.date.substring(0, 10)) <= this.date2);
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating the list on the change of the first Date input.
Update the list onChange of the first Date if the second Date already been selected.
Change your code as below.

Instead of

```
  changeFirstInput(e) {
    this.date1 = new Date(e.target.value.replace(this.pattern, '$3-$2-$1'));
  }
```

Try this

```
  changeFirstInput(e) {
    this.date1 = new Date(e.target.value.replace(this.pattern, '$3-$2-$1'));
    if (this.date2) {
      this.display = this.obj.filter(o => new Date(o.date.substring(0, 10)) >= this.date1 && new Date(o.date.substring(0, 10)) <= this.date2);
    }
  }
```